# React native chip selection not updating in View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`

```
export default function ChipsTest({ }) {

const interests = [{ name: 'ABC', selected: false, id:1, }, { name: 'XYZ', selected: false, id:2 }, { name: 'Bla bla', selected: false, id: 3 } ];

return ( <View style={styles.container}> {interests.map((interest, index) => ( <TouchableOpacity> <Chip onPress={() =>  { interest.selected = !interest.selected; interest.name = 'Ali'; console.log(interests);      

    }}
          key={interest.id}
          selected={ interest.selected}
        > {interest.name} </Chip>
   
      </TouchableOpacity>

  ))}
</View>
```

);
`

## Hi, I am using react native chips on select I am updating value of selected item but its not reflecting in UI/View. I am able to see value updated in variable/ console. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `useState` hook to solve your problem.
Basically, React native will re-render your screen's UI if the state changes.
More here: https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/

Also, I'm not sure what `<Chip/>` component is. I would move `onPress` event listener to `<TouchableOpacity onPress={...}>` OR keep it in `<Chip>` and remove `<TouchableOpacity>`.

And then, I would wrap `{interest.name}` within `<Text> {interest.name} </Text>`

Good luck!